# Getting EXACT matches from full-text search returned first?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, relevance

I am using the below code for example:

```
SELECT *, (MATCH (`wm`, `locn`, `gns`) AGAINST('foot locker')) AS score FROM `example_table` WHERE MATCH (`wm`, `locn`, `gns`) AGAINST('foot locker')) order by score DESC;
```

However even though EXACT matches exist in the `wm` column, the EXACT match doesn't appear untiil the 8th result. The ones ahead of it all have the phrase too, but also some following text. I checked the `locn`, `gns` fields to see how they compared and nothing really stands out that should make the others score higher.

I did some reading about using `BOOLEAN MODE` but nothing I read there seemed like it would help my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if this helps anyone else I was able to achieve what I wanted by doing this:

```
SELECT *, 
  CASE WHEN wm = 'foot locker' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS score, 
  MATCH (`wm`, `locn`, `gns`) AGAINST('foot locker') AS score2 
FROM 
  `example_table` 
WHERE 
  MATCH (`wm`, `locn`, `gns`) AGAINST('foot locker')) 
ORDER BY
  score DESC, score2 DESC;
```